# ORACLE SQL - How to insert data with a user defined Function

Tags: oracle, function

I am a little bit new in Oracle and I am going to write a function which can insert data into another table in oracle SQL.

There is a Grade Table:

```
CREATE TABLE GRADE 
( ID NUMBER(38,0), 
  SUBJECTID NUMBER(38,0), 
  STUDENTID NUMBER(38,0), 
  GRADE NUMBER(38,0))
```

There is AVGGRADE Table:

```
CREATE TABLE AVGGRADE 
( ID NUMBER(38,0), 
  STUDENTID NUMBER(38,0), 
  AVG NUMBER(38,0))
```

I am going to calculate the average of grades in Grade table then insert them into AVGGRADE table by function. But I do not know how. I am appreciate you to help me.

Comment: Stop and just **don't**. Data should be kept redundancy free to avoid the possibilities of inconsistencies. So writing an average over one table into another isn't a good thing to do. If you need the average, you can always query it and get the **right** result. For convenience you can create a view that stores such a query so you don't have to repeat it every time.

Comment: It was just an example. I am going to solve my problem.

Comment: If for some reason you need to insert an output of some query into another table, then it would be better to use materialized view and not to reinvent the wheel. This does exactly what is described and may keep tables in consistent state without extra code. Writing a function that executes the query and inserts data into another table is pointless even for educational purposes (educational cases should at least look like real cases): 1) function with side effects is very confusing. 2) you may do it with plain SQL, there's no need to use a function for AVG calculation

Answer (score 0):

> if you are creating a new table just to select average grade its not
> recommended to do in such way, it may create issues later on when you
> want to change data and will be difficult to mange it.
>
> In case, your data is so high may be you need to de de-normalize your
> table then you can proceed with it. I think in your case it will be
> very rare to de-normalize table because data may not reach so
> much

i think simple query could do the job

```
select
    studentid
    avg(grade) as avg_grade
from
    GRADE 
group by  studentid
```

Comment: I don't think so; ID - although not explicitly stated - looks like a *primary key* column for the table, so you'd actually get as many rows as there are in the table, not averages per student. I believe you should remove the ID column from the query.

Comment: yes true i meant to say average function should do the job, id primary key so it should be removed from grouping

Answer (score 0):

I guess that's for educational purposes; otherwise, a view would do (as sticky bit commented). Here's my suggestion:

- create a sequence (which will be used to populate `avggrade.id` column)
- create a function which will calculate average grade for a student
- create a procedure which will call the function and insert result it returns into the target table

Something like this:

```
SQL> create sequence seqgrade;

Sequence created.

SQL> create or replace function f_avg_grade (par_studentid in grade.studentid%type)
  2    return number
  3  is
  4    l_avg number;
  5  begin
  6    select round(avg(g.grade), 2)
  7    into l_avg
  8    from grade g
  9    where g.studentid = par_studentid;
 10
 11    return l_avg;
 12  end f_avg_grade;
 13  /

Function created.

SQL> create or replace procedure p_avg_grade (par_studentid in grade.studentid%type)
  2  is
  3  begin
  4    insert into avggrade (id, studentid, avg_grade)
  5      values (seqgrade.nextval, par_studentid, f_avg_grade(par_studentid));
  6  end;
  7  /

Procedure created.
```

Testing:

```
SQL> select * From grade order by studentid;

        ID  SUBJECTID  STUDENTID      GRADE
---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
         1        100       1000          2
         2        101       1000          3
         3        102       1000          5
         4         10       2000          3

SQL> begin
  2    p_avg_grade(1000);
  3  end p_avg_grade;
  4  /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> select * from avggrade;

        ID  STUDENTID  AVG_GRADE
---------- ---------- ----------
         1       1000       3,33

SQL>
```